# Coupling mechanisms

Tags: electromagnetism, high-current, copper, coupling

What are some mechanisms that one material can be coupled electromagnetically to another, other than basic tranformer action?

The model I'm considering is a high current electrode, about 1.5m wide, surrounded by a copper ring with a inner to outer radius of 13 cm(quite thick) and a height of 40cm. The copper ring is completely isolated un ungrounded and an average current of +- 70kA flows in the electrode.

I've considered many ways in which the current in the electrode could be coupled to the ring. I'm pretty sure Ive considered all mechanisms of coupling and all indication show that the ring does not have any effect. What other factors might I consider to completely disqualify the ring as a loss machanism?

Comment: 1.5m wide or 1.5cm? A picture would help. Also knowing what operating frequency you are running at would be useful to state.

Comment: Is the copper ring connected to anything else? Does the voltage on this electrode relative to that something else vary at all?

Comment: For that matter, does the electrode voltage vary relative to Earth? How much? What frequency? Or, is it significantly different from Earth, even at DC?

Answer (score 2):

Copper is weakly diamagnetic.(This means it generates its own weaker, induced magnetic field which opposes any magnetic field in which it is placed. Thus, copper is always repelled from a magnetic field or other magnet). Under normal circumstances this can be ignored but given the size of current through the electrode the effect could be substantial. As you state the current is +/- 70kA I can infer that it is AC rather than DC. If so this could result in eddy current formation as the magnetic field changes.

[image]

Comment: I think you mean 'as the magnetic field changes'.